# How to require user login from code in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I currently have a RealmResourceProvider for my realm "test". Its URL is http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test/domainextension. I want the user to be authenticated in the realm in order to access this page. However, right now anyone can access this page, even if not authenticated. Is there some kind of magic function like :

```
session.requireUserLogin();
```

I want the user to be redirected to the realm authentication form, and then to the RealmResourceProvider URL when logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to authentication and set up authentication flow, there are few existing flows which you can change as per your requirements. e.g. for username and password you can make the username password form required. Then you should also check out the binding tab in authentication to bind the flow to actions.

Comment: Hello ! I tried the different bindings etc. already but the problem is that the access to the RealmResourceProvider doesn't trigger any authentication flow. How can I trigger a specific flow for instance ? I haven't found anything like this in the doc

Answer (score 0):

The authentication checking needs to be done inside the resource method.

I've used [AppAuthManager](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/services/managers/AppAuthManager.html) and the following code for checking in the past:

```
AuthResult authResult = new AppAuthManager().authenticateBearerToken(session, session.getContext().getRealm());

if (authResult == null)
    throw new NotAuthorizedException("Bearer");
```

where `session` is a `KeycloakSession` instance.

When `NotAuthorizedException` is thrown it will trigger the login screen if this is being called as part of the Keycloak UI interface (such as if you have written a Keycloak extension that adds some UI), but it won't magically redirect to the HTML login form by itself.

You can additionally check roles, etc. from the `authResult` by creating a new `AdminAuth` object and querying that:

```
AdminAuth adminAuth = new AdminAuth(realm, authResult.getToken(), authResult.getUser(), client);
if (!auth.hasRealmRole("some-custom-role"))
    throw new ForbiddenException("User does not have required role");
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit the "if this is being called as part of the Keycloak UI interface" please ? I am already throwing this exception as part of a @GET request, but it doesn't redirect me to the HTML login form.